# Is wiping memory at code/end good practise?

Tags: memory

Sometimes passwords/hash/keys & other private information is stored in variables and hence in memory/RAM during code execution.

while some situations (i.e. Linux Kernels see here [Is there any Linux distro or kernel patch that wipes a process memory space after the process exits?](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/42179/13609) ) care about wiping used memory I was wondering more about the broader picture:

**Question is therefore:**
Should the programmer of code care about wiping (i.e. zerosetting) sensitive information by her/himself?
More precise should I do something like this

```
int main()
{
    char bufferWithSecret [10];
    sprintf (bufferWithSecret, "%d",generateKey());

    // do some stuff
    // ...
    // ...

    sprintf (bufferWithSecret, "000000000"); // wipe the memory
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wipe sensitive information early, you *might* arguably reduce the time window for an exploit while your program is running, but in general (and in particular in a when-process-exits context) it's a pretty useless endeavor.

It's **much** more important to lock memory that contains sensitive data, so it cannot be swapped out. Sensitive data being swapped out is something you want to avoid at all cost.
The worst thing about a page with sensitive data being swapped out is, by the way, not even the fact that it's written to disk, but the fact that you cannot guarantee that it will ever be deleted from disk again (due to drives doing wear-levelling). This is totally out of control of the operating system, or even your application.

Memory pages are zeroed before being handed to a new process on every non-joke operating system, so zeroing them manually does not really add anything (not on a *realistic* threat model, anyway).
Of course someone might use a DMA exploit (such as Firewire) to read physical RAM pages that have not been cleared, but they could already do that while your program is running, insofar not much is gained by erasing them a little earlier.

Comment: my joke operation system/setting is called one of the many JavaScript engine implementations. With all the GC and caching and optimization I am unsure if the "OS" cleares memory principles applies. Therefore I assumed that there are joke OS/situation and hence to be sure the step to wipe sensitive data is a recomended best practise step, just in case. Thanks for the insights of the answer.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace: The OS will clear the memory before giving it to another process, however a browser's JavaScript engine might easily reuse memory for another script without it being returned to the OS meanwhile, and therefore clearing the memory to prevent cross-site disclosure is a good idea.  On the other hand, Javascript shouldn't be allowing read of uninitialized variables in the first place.  This is more a problem for unmanaged languages.

Comment: I still somewhat disagree with your answer. Security is all about defense in depth; wiping secrets from memory as soon as is feasible can dramatically reduce the real-world impact of vulnerabilities like memory leaks (e.g., Heartbleed).

Comment: @BenVoigt But the OS will not clear the memory on process destruction or `munmap()`, so just because a correctly behaving kernel will initialize the memory does not mean it will actually be wiped, opening up room for other bugs. This is the reason grsecurity clears this memory when returning to the kernel when cleaning up process resources, and the reason why OpenBSD's libc poisons values on `free()`.

Answer (score 1):

No you should not do something "like that".  You should use a library function which is intended for wiping sensitive data.

The problem with using general-purpose routines such as `sprintf`, `memset`, or your own loop is that the compiler may perform data dependency analysis, determine that the new value is unimportant, and optimize away the write.

Windows provides a [`SecureZeroMemory` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366877.aspx) for exactly this reason.  Some frameworks make this very easy, others not at all.  You might check this question for more information:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166986/clearing-memory-in-different-languges-for-security

Finally, `SecureZeroMemory` and .NET `SecureString` only exist because this IS a good practice.